# ajax loading image not displaying

Tags: ajax

I have tried many ways to implement loading effect while Ajax is loading using gif image, but have failed to do so successfully. GIF image just doesn't show up at all.

How to make sure that loading gif is displayed and hides before displaying fetched data perfectly, so that applications authenticity is not compromised.

Thanks a lot !!!

```
<div id="loader"> </div>



$.ajax({
                            type:"GET",
                            url:"ajax/forClickedDate.php",
                            dataType:'JSON',
                            data:"date=" + currentYear + '-' + currentMonthInteger + '-' + current.html() + "&id=" + "<?php echo $id;?>",
                            beforeSend:function(){
                                // this is where we append a loading image
                                $('#loader').append('<div class="loading"><img src="<?php echo IMAGE_PATH;?>blue.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
                            },
                            success:function(data){
                                $('#loader').hide();
                                //do something with the data

                                $('#currentAppointment').append(data);
                                   $('#currentAppointment').append('<p>' + data[b].name + '-' + data[b].task + '</p>');
                                // }
                            },
```

Also tried:

```
$(function(){   
             $('#loader').hide();

             $('#loader')
                 .ajaxStart(function(){
                     $(this).show();
                 }).ajaxStop(function(){
                     $(this).hide();
             });
```

Comment: May be your IMAGE_PATH is wrong. That's why it doesn't showup.

Comment: Have already taken care of it..path is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the absolute path to your .gif image?

Try to set this absolute path manually not using PHP. If it works well, than something wrong with IMAGE_PATH.

Comment: try to appy this approach. 1) Copy the absolute path to .gif and paste it right to $('#loader'). Like this. $('#loader').html("http://yoursite.com/images/loader.gif"). Comment all other operations so they not affect your code in any way. This way you will be absolutely sure that all you function does is showing your loader

Comment: I tried your approach, it worked the first time, but thereafter loading image didn't show up. Any ideas???

Comment: Good sign. At least it showed up.I guess the problem is that when you hide  $('#loader').hide(); your loader you never show it afterwards when you try to call ajax function. You need to  call $('#loader').show(); in the beforeSend section at the very top.

Comment: It finally worked after some messing around..u guided me in the right direction ...thanx a lot.